# NullPointerException when trying to show ProgressDialog from a Static AsyncTask method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I have a static AsyncTask in my MainActivity. I run this asynctask to download data from a URL. I'm trying to show a progress dialog from the async task but it crashes on this line: `private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);`

I pass the context through to the AsyncTask.

Here is my code:

```
private static class MyTasksParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

    public MyTasksParse(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        this.dialog.setMessage("Downloading Files... Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        //get the url and parse it 
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried casting `mContext` as an `Activity` as follows: 
`private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);` but still the same error.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can help out, it would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: try to initialize it in the onPreExecute method

Comment: Sure `private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);` line causing issue because `mContext` is `null` move `dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);` after `mContext = context;` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `NullPointerException` beacuse the variable `mContext` is null at this point:

```
    private static class MyTasksParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private Context mContext;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
...
...
```

this will help:

```
private static class MyTasksParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public MyTasksParse(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext)
    }
```

When you receive the value of `context` in the constructor then you can instatiate correctly the `ProgressDialog` =).

Comment: @Mark117: Because class is static probably also getting warning when creating object of `MyTasksParse ` ?

Answer (score 1):

`mContext` is `null` when you pass it to the constructor of `ProgressDialog`, thus throwing a `NullPointerException`.

This should work:

```
private Context mContext;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public MyTasksParse(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mContext` is `null` when you initialise the `ProgressDialog`. That's why the crash is happening.

You need to change:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

to:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
```

And initialise the progress dialog in `onPreExecute`:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NullPointerException beacuse mContext is null.
You need to init ProgressDialog inside constructor like

```
public MyTasksParse(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext)
}
```